# There is a find function....Is there an "opposite of find" function?

Tags: string, string-function

I want to know if you can find a letter by entering the position of it so it gives you the letter back.

In other words, I want a function that is the opposite of the find function?

P.S. if myString is a string and I input the position of the letter I want the letter in that
position to come back.

Comment: `String.charAt()`?

Comment: What language are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

You could use indexing like:
(python)

```py
myString = "dog"
myString[1] # -> "o"
```

Or specific method like "myString.charAt()" (Java) (*comment by a_horse_with_no_name*).
That depends on language.

Answer (score 0):

In Java & JavaScript:

```
myStr.charAt(index)
```

In C#, C, C++, Python, PHP, Ruby you use indexing with square brackets:

```
myStr[index]
```

Similarly, in F#, you write

```
myStr.[index]
```